# Собрать значения после цикла и просуммировать

Tags: python

возник такой вопрос:
У меня есть ввод данных в таком формате:

```
l = int(input("Задайте количество звеньев: "))
 
d = [int(i) for i in input("Задайте шаг звеньев: "). split()]
```

Мне необходимо получить первое и крайнее звено:

```
l_list = [x for x in range(1, i +1)]
first_and_last_l = [l_list[0], l_list[-1]]
```

Затем с помощью цикла я выполняю действия для каждого значения списка:

```
for i in range(len(d)) :
    f = 5 * (6 * d[i])
```

Затем мне необходимо провести вычисления только для первого и крайнего звена:

```
 M = (f / 5)
```

Но в итоге, как и должно быть, в выводе я получаю:
Например l = 5:

```
2
2
2
2
2
```

Т.е. пять выводов результата вычисления М
Вопрос, как собрать эти результаты М и просуммировать в один???
Все результаты и выводы условные, важна лишь суть

Answer (score 0):

`Вопрос, как собрать эти результаты М и просуммировать в один???`

что мешает иметь счетчик и каждый раз увеличивать его на `M`?

или сохранять в массиве и затем вызвать функцию `sum()`

P.S.

Непонятна в общем задача - вы используете только крайние значения (первый и последний), зачем дальше что-то вычислять для промежуточных (у вас это `f`)

вы бы более корректно задачу и пример описали (в примере хотя бы переменные назовите одинаково, а то, что за `i`, что за `d`?)

P.P.S.

кстати

```
d = [int(i) for i in input("Задайте шаг звеньев: "). split()]
```

можно превратить в:

```
d = list(map(int, input("Задайте шаг звеньев: ").split()))
```

а

```
l_list = [x for x in range(1, i +1)]
```

в

```
l_list = list(range(1, i + 1))
```